# Python regex for mixture of English and Chinese characters unable to return matches

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am stuck and need some help in pointing the mistake.
I am trying to extract a portion of the html code from a webpage which is done using tables, and with same class and id in many places. Hence I am unable to use only BeautifulSoup4 to extract it. I will need a little regex to extract. Only then to use html parser to extract the info I need based on the returned string from regex. But the problem arises when the regex is unable to work with some of the chinese characters. I have read somewhere it is related to need to change the string to unicode to work, but can't get it to work on myself. Part of the code as below:

```
import requests
import bs4
import re

fetch = requests.get('http://www.check4d.com')

mo = re.search(u'<td class="resultdamacailable">Da Ma Cai 1+3D 大馬彩(.+?)</table></div>' , fetch.text)
matched = mo.group()
print matched
```

the error i get is

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\check4d_r5_today.py", line 98, in 
    matched = mo.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

part of the html code:

```
<div class="outerbox"><table class="resultTable" align="center"><tr><td colspan="5"><table class="resultTable2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="resultdamacailable" style="width:20%"><img src=""/></td><td class="resultdamacailable">Da Ma Cai 1+3D 大馬彩</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5"><table class="resultTable2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5"><tr><td class="resultdrawdate">Date: 03-05-2016 (Tue)</td><td class="resultdrawdate">Draw No: 4359/16</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5"><table class="resultTable2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width:45%" class="resultprizelable">1st Prize 首獎</td><td class="resulttop">1002</td></tr><tr><td style="width:45%" class="resultprizelable">2nd Prize 二獎</td><td class="resulttop">3605</td></tr><tr><td style="width:45%" class="resultprizelable">3rd Prize 三獎</td><td class="resulttop">0010</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5" class="resultprizelable">Special 特別獎</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom">8079</td><td class="resultbottom">2293</td><td class="resultbottom">1891</td><td class="resultbottom">7657</td><td class="resultbottom">5781</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom">4989</td><td class="resultbottom">4586</td><td class="resultbottom">6868</td><td class="resultbottom">3129</td><td class="resultbottom">3635</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom" colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan="5" class="resultprizelable">Consolation 安慰獎</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom">0901</td><td class="resultbottom">8750</td><td class="resultbottom">0152</td><td class="resultbottom">2929</td><td class="resultbottom">4220</td></tr><tr><td class="resultbottom">6213</td><td class="resultbottom">5185</td><td class="resultbottom">8283</td><td class="resultbottom">9864</td><td class="resultbottom">3029</td></tr></table></div>
```

I think it must have something to do with the Chinese characters, as after I remove it, it returns OK. But leaving the Chinese characters will return matches that I do not want.

Comment: I don't believe python 2.7 (as I assume you're using based on your directory name) fully supports unicode natively/transparently. It helps to read up on this in the docs, and compare python 2 and 3: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html, especially the part about regex: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-regular-expressions

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.check4d.com')
html = str(url.read()).encode('cp437', 'ignore') #ignores chinese characters in page
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
content = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "outerbox" },recursive=True)

#Da Ma Cai Data is stored in content[3]
```